# How to override equality method in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm reading a [book on Smalltalk](http://books.google.ro/books/about/Smalltalk_Objects_and_Design.html?id=W8_Une9cbbgC&redir_esc=y) and I have an exercise about the *anomaly of disappearing element* I'm not able to solve.

```
Object subclass: Book [
    | isbn |
    <comment: 'A book class'>

    setIsbn: anIsbn [
        isbn := anIsbn.
    ]

    getIsbn [
        ^isbn.
    ]

    = anotherBook [
        ^self getIsbn = anotherBook getIsbn.
    ]
]

| Library |

Library := Set new: 100.
Library add: (Book new setIsbn: '0-671-2-158-1').
(Library includes: (Book new setIsbn: '0-671-2-158-1')) printNl.
```

I read I have to override the `hash` method too, but I don't know how to do it. How do I amend the `Book` class in order to avoid the *anomaly*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't really tell what are you asking about, but to override hash, you should do the same as with `=`, which you have overridden as well, just by including different definition. So you do something like:

```
hash [
  "return hash here"
]
```

If you are asking what hash should be like… well think about it like that: objects that are equal have to have the same hash (but this doesn't have to work the other way around). So I'd suggest you to do something like

```
hash [
  ^ self getIsbn hash
]
```

Also about disappearing element. Set is a hashed collection. This means that before comparing it's element with the one you are looking for, it select's a subset by hash. So if you are not overriding hash it may select a subset that won't contain your desired element.

In the end I'd suggest you to use some different implementation of Smalltalk, because my head hurt when I was starting to learn it with [gnu-smalltalk](/questions/tagged/gnu-smalltalk). Personaly I use [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) it provides a nice UI and allows you to see what you override, allows you to debug, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot, this was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know what piece of data I was supposed to hash when I overridden the method. But it makes sense now.

Comment: +1 for the #hash override, but I'd have left out the last paragraph, personally.

Comment: @FrankShearar yes, you are right. But I don't care. It was really pain for me to program in gnu-smalltalk because you don't know what you have in the image, where is your code etc... Maybe I can help this guy by my last sentence. (Yes, I can recommend other smalltalk dialects, but I don't want to recommend something I'm not sure about)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few further Smalltalk idiomatic issues with your code:

- normally accessors in Smalltalk don't use get and set. So you'd have `isbn: anIsbn` and `isbn`.
- you probably want to create an extra constructor that has the ISBN as a parameter so you don't have to send both `new` and the setter yourself:

  ```
  Book>>onIsbn: anIsbn    

      ^self new
           isbn: anIsbn;
           yourself
  ```

Comment: Some bug in the markdown recognition makes the last code rather unreadable

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is never override `#`= without overriding `#hash`